# Was there a Norse custom of "one keeps what one defends"?

Tags: economy, vikings

Watching a Viking TV series this cropped up where a farmer was challenged to fight for his farm. It appears that the Norse did not have title deeds but rather relied on the sword to settle ownership whether of land or a woman?

Am I wrong?  What was the custom called and how was it implemented?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norse_law

Comment: @TomasBy - After reading that page over, and following some of its links, it seems to me that it does not trivially answer this question at all. In fact, I'm still not sure what the answer is.

Comment: @T.E.D. the answer is no there was no such televison-bollox custom, they had laws.

Comment: The Wikipedia page doesn't seem to reference property law.

Comment: @TomasBy, [trial by combat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_by_combat) has been a part of numerous legal codes.

Comment: @Mark - When I looked into that, it looks like the Nowegian sources do document it being used, but they also seem to say it was used for disputes of honor (no mention of property). Basically this seems like the same good-old dueling depicted in Hamilton, but with melee weapons. But that was probably later, so what it would have been used for in Norse times we're not sure.

Comment: [PDF](https://archive.org/details/corpusiurissueo09swedgoog): pp 123-131 inheritance, pp. 131-135 marriage, pp. 141-151 "real estate", pp. 152-160 theft ([old Westrogothic law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A4stg%C3%B6talagen)).

Comment: @TomasBy - That's a good 3 centuries after the end of the Viking era though. From what I read on your first link, in the Viking era they would have been relying on rulings from Things, not on written laws.

Comment: No, less than two? Viking era ended 1066. And the laws were much older than the earliest manuscripts we happen to have. The laws were an oral tradition for a long time.

Comment: From that Westrogothic link, it looks like they have no evidence for written law prior to 1250. From the first link, it seems to say they started writing down the Icelandic Thing's laws in 1117. Disputes about rough numbers aside, that doesn't push written law back into the Viking era.

Comment: "You keep what you can defend" is the root of *all* societies. Why else would we band together and spend gazillions of currency units on the military? Because if you don't, soon someone else keeps what you failed to defend.  The Vikings just did it at a more retail level than we do.

Comment: @T.E.D. there is some evidence in the sagas, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torgny_the_Lawspeaker

Comment: @ScottishWalrus: Would you mind saying what the show was you watched? Also, title deeds per se would not have existed in Norse society.

Comment: @T.E.D. the [Tune rune stone](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunesteinen) (AD 200–450) contains references to inheritance law (the English wiki page is incomplete).

Answer (score 4):

It is difficult to address a scene from 'a Viking TV show' historically, but perhaps the show was referring to the form of ritualized combat or dueling known as [Holmgang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holmgang).  Without a detailed description or link to the scene it would be difficult to tell if the conditions fit. The description from the Wikipedia page does seem to indicate the possibility existed (emphasis mine):

> Professional duelists used holmgangs as a form of legalized robbery;
> they could ***claim rights to land, women, or property***, and then ***prove
> their claims in the duel at the expense of the legitimate owner***. Many
> sagas describe ***berserks who abused holmgang in this way***. In large part
> due to such practices, holmgangs were outlawed in Iceland in 1006, as
> a result of the duel between Gunnlaugr Ormstunga and Hrafn
> Önundarson,[2] and in Norway in 1014.